# Linq GroupBy with multiple columns of type List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I don't know what syntax I should use to make group by with multiple columns work with indexes.

Let assume that I have structure like this:

```
    var listToGroupBy = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"},
            new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"},
            new List<string> {"d", "k", "c"},
            new List<string> {"d", "z", "c"}
        };
```

Next I want to group by 1st and 3rd item.  I'd like to use syntax similar the one below but so far I wasn't successful.

```
var groupByResult = listToGroupBy.GroupBy(c => new { c[0], c[2] });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to name the fields in your anonymous type:

```
var groupByResult = listToGroupBy.GroupBy(c => new { c0 = c[0], c3 = c[3] });
```

Comment: I think you're right. Linq can imply the field names when you use dot notation, but can't when you're just using an array index.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Douglas' answer, you need to explicitly name your fields if you don't use dot notation.

When you use dot notation, Linq can figure out what to name the columns based on the name of the property. But since you're using an array index, it doesn't know what to name it.

So, in the example below, Linq would know to use `Something` and `SomethingElse` as the field names.

```
var groupByResult = listToGroupBy.GroupBy(c => new {c.Something, c.SomethingElse});
```

Like douglas said, you can achieve the same result as dot notation by naming your fields:

```
var groupByResult = listToGroupBy.GroupBy(c => new { Something = c[0], SomethingElse = c[3] });
```